# VBScript How can I include parentheses in a string

Tags: string, vbscript

I am playing around with VBScript and I want to have one script make a different script depending on the user's input. For example, typing "make me a joke program" will create a script that will randomly tell a joke separate from the original script. To be exact, this is the Microsoft Script Host VBS, not vb.net or anything else. Anyways, the program creates the vbs file and writes to it. However, if I try to write parentheses to the file, it doesn't work.

```
jokeScript.WriteLine("x=msgbox("Would you like to hear a joke?", 1+32,"Joke")")
```

Is there any way I can include parentheses in a string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think really what you want is to escape the double quotes.

```
WScript.Echo("x=msgbox (""Would  you like to hear a joke?"",1+32 ,""Joke"")")
```